# How do I achieve the "GitHub browse repo effect" (update URL without refreshing the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, url, refresh

When I browse a repo in GitHub (example: https://github.com/sizzlelab/kassi) and click a folder, it loads the folder with a cool javascript animation, moving stuff to the left, instead of reloading the whole page. However, the URL of the page is still updated on every click.

How do I achieve this? To my knowledge, you cannot update the page URL from javascript, so you need to refresh the page. My guess is that they do a partial caching of the page so that it does not seem to reload and then run the javascript animation after reload. Am I on the right track? Any pointers on how this can be achieved? My environment is jQuery and rails, but a general advice will help also.

Comment: Saw this today and was also curious. But not enough to dig in :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub Slider JQuery Plugin...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419469/github-slider-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Merlyn: yeah, that question is close, but I'm more interested in the method of updating url via refreshing the page than the actual slide effect they have in GitHub, and there seems to be no answers to that in the other question. But thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is watch this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state

in combination with jQuery UI effect "slide" - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

good luck!

Comment: Hey cool, how didn't I manage to find that before! Thanks a lot, just the directions I wanted!

Answer (score 4):

You can read about this behaviour in spec — [History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/author/history.html) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) in section "Adding and modifying history entries".

Comment: Thanks! So it's HTML5 stuff then? Any ideas on what's the browser support for that currently? And does it gracefully degrade, and if yes, how? To simply refreshing the whole page?

Well, just a few quick questions, I dig in to those links now. :)

Comment: Modernizr checks History API something like this: function isHistorySupport() { return !!(window.history && history.pushState); }

Comment: @Kusti the bottom of the MDN link has browser compatibility

Comment: @Kusti: According to [the blog page linked](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) from [the dupe question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419469/github-slider-jquery-plugin), HTML5 manages the history changes, and CSS3 handles the sliding.

Comment: There is an nice library that can help emulate new History API via hashbang — https://github.com/balupton/history.js

Comment: Ok, cool! But, is there any way to achieve this also in Internet Explorer? According to the MDN link no version of Internet Explorer, even 9, supports this. I do not (necessarily) need the fancy animation part, just a way to reload new content and change the URL without refreshing the whole page.

Facebook also seems to do something like this: when I click around in the inbox, only then contents of the inbox change so that it seems the whole page is not refreshing even though the URL changes. I have a mac so I'm currently not able to test whether this works also on IE.

Comment: @Kusti: Depending on your requirements, if you can simply hook the link with JS and reroute it to an Ajax call to load the new page into a div, without "refreshing" the whole page.  This won't solve the history problem, tho.